# Remove double quotes from a specific value after importing a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm importing an array of an external stored JSON-file. In the JSON, there is a key-value pair 'dataType', where the value stored as a string. For a 3rd party application expect an Array with some values as a property without double quotes.

**Current status:**

```
...{id: "label", dataType: "tableau.dataTypeEnum.string"}...
```

**Expected format:**

```
...{id: "label", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string}...
```

I've tried it like this, but the double quotes are still in there. Thank you for your hints.

**Script**:

```
...
schemaFromFile = JSON.parse(getRemote());
/*
 * Convert dataType to property to avoid dbl quoted values
*/

Object.keys(schemaFromFile).forEach(function(key) {

   if(schemaFromFile[key].hasOwnProperty('dataType'))
      schemaFromFile[key].resolve = eval(schemaFromFile[key].resolve);

});

console.log('schema', schema)

function getRemote() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: schemaURL,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
};
...
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with sample in- and the resulting output so we have something to work with.

Comment: You don't need `schemaFromFile[key]`. Just `key` is the same and faster.

Comment: Would [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) work?

Comment: I would seriously reconsider your approach since it requires the use of `eval` (which is notoriously insecure). something like a set of known types mapped to the appropriate names would be a much safer and much more debuggable approach.

Comment: @Rojo How is `key` the same as `schemaFromFile[key]`? o.O

Comment: [`key` is the actual value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @DavidCulbreth has a good idea: create an object for the datatypes, that has the key of `tableau.dataTypeEnum.string` in string format and the value of `tableau.dataTypeEnum.string` as the variable itself. Then just call on that object / key to get the appropriate value.

Comment: @Rojo Yes, but OP want's the element stored at `schemaFromFile[key]` and not the key (name of the property) - `schemaFromFile` is something like `{ "file1": { label: ..., dataType: ... }, "file2": { label: ..., dataType: ... } }` and `key` will be `"file1"`, `"file2"`, ...

Comment: '@DavidCulbreth, @imvain2 That is a great idea!